# Golden Ratio of Primes (Amateur)

Tags: prime-numbers, golden-ratio

Unable to find information elsewhere, so I'll try here.

What two consecutive primes are closest to producing the Golden Ratio? Or two of any Primes?

Has this been determined?

Thanks!

Comment: take two consecutive Fibonacci numbers, then take the next prime after each. This way you can get as close to the golden ratio as you like, it just may take a while to find the primes.

Comment: *Consecutive* primes, on the other hand, tend to be much closer together than the golden ratio, so I'd be surprised if you can do better than 5 and 3.

Comment: By a result of Nagura, past $25$ there is always a prime between the prime $p$ and $p(1+1/5)$. So for consecutive the search is short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of any two primes...? Well, for each prime $p$, let's compute the minimum value of $d = \|\log{\phi p} - \log{q}\|$ over all primes $q$. Then pairs $(p,q)$ with a ratio close to $\phi$ will have a small value of $d$. Here's a plot of $\log d$ versus $p$ for $p<10^4$:

[image]

Good pairs stand out as downward spikes on the graph. Some notable pairs are $(29,47)$, $(97,157)$, $(563,911)$, $(631,1021)$, $(1453,2351)$ and the best pair in this range: $(2207,3571)$. For that last pair, we have $2207\phi = 3571.00101\ldots$, which is pretty impressive!

For fun, here's the raw data for $p<100$, formatted as $p, q, d, \log d$:

`3, 5, 0.0296138, -3.51951
5, 7, 0.14474, -1.93282
7, 11, 0.0292267, -3.53267
11, 17, 0.0458938, -3.08143
13, 23, 0.089333, -2.41538
17, 29, 0.0528707, -2.93991
19, 31, 0.0083364, -4.78712
23, 37, 0.00578813, -5.15195
29, 47, 0.00163995, -6.41309
31, 53, 0.0550929, -2.89873
37, 59, 0.0145923, -4.22726
41, 67, 0.00990873, -4.61434
43, 71, 0.0202679, -3.89872
47, 79, 0.0380884, -3.26784
53, 83, 0.0326631, -3.42151
59, 97, 0.0159617, -4.13756
61, 97, 0.0173747, -4.05274
67, 109, 0.00544344, -5.21334
71, 113, 0.0165039, -4.10416
73, 113, 0.0442834, -3.11714
79, 127, 0.00647259, -5.04018
83, 137, 0.0199285, -3.9156
89, 149, 0.0340981, -3.37851
97, 157, 0.000323002, -8.03785`

Comment: Wow! Thanks! What program did you use for the graph? I would love to be able to calculate this myself even further!

Comment: I'm a little bit ashamed to admit that I wrote my own C++ code to produce the data. It took me 80 lines, whereas I'm sure a lot of people around here could do it in two lines of Python and a well-chosen library. Worse, I shipped with a bug caused by a poorly implemented premature optimization: my code skipped the prime number 2! Well, what can I say... it's a Friday. :-P The graph itself is Excel. As for the best programming environment for you to get your hands dirty... I don't know. Whatever you're most familiar with? You could try asking another question here at math.SE.

Comment: I'm impressed. I looked at your profile and you're a wizard compared to me. "What sorcery is this?!" is the best reaction I have to your work on vimeo.com. I haven't taken anything past algebra two (and even then I've forgotten it), I'm just an amateur who loves math as a spare-time hobby (like doodling) but has yet to have a formal education in it. I don't know a programming language, but I'd like to see the code anyway. P.S. Here's a site you might like: http://www.complexification.net/

Comment: Ooh, pretty, thanks for the link! Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/z0GDJhk3. It's a fixed version, so the first line it outputs is now "2, 3, 0.0757467, -2.58036". Please keep in mind that this code is terrible and would never be checked into a shipping product as such. It's just a hacked-together... well, hack. :) If you're interested in generative art, and you're looking to learn your first language, maybe try Processing? It's at https://www.processing.org.

Comment: Thanks! What compiler do you use?

Comment: For this project, Apple LLVM 5.1 hosted by Xcode. The code is simple enough that it should be easy to port it to any environment, if it doesn't Just Work as-is.

Comment: For anyone who's curious, this is the pair that's closest to phi up to one million.       943097, 1525963, 4.50902e-10, -21.5198

Comment: 2207 and 3571 also happen to be Lucas numbers.